# Can't create table in database

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I have my code to make a room booking database, but whenever i reference one part for a foreign key in a table, an error comes out and i still cant solve the problem

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ROOM;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMER;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ROOMBOOKING;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS CUSTOMERFEEDBACK;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS PAYMENT;
CREATE TABLE ROOM(

    RoomNo INT(5) NOT NULL,
    PricePerNight DOUBLE,
    Type VARCHAR(255),

    PRIMARY KEY (RoomNo)
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(

    CustomerID INT(10) NOT NULL,
    CustName VARCHAR (255),
    CustPhoneNo INT (15),
    Custemail VARCHAR (255),
    CustDOB DATE,

    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID)
);



CREATE TABLE ROOMBOOKING(

    CustomerID int(10) NOT NULL,
    RoomNo int(5) NOT NULL,
    CheckInDate date NOT NULL,
    CheckOutDate date,
    CustSpecialRequest VARCHAR (500),
    PRIMARY KEY (CustomerID,CheckInDate,RoomNo),
    FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES CUSTOMER(CustomerID),
    FOREIGN KEY (RoomNo) REFERENCES ROOM(RoomNo)
);

CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERFEEDBACK(

    CommentDate date NOT NULL,
    CustomerID int(10) NOT NULL,
    RoomNo int(5) NOT NULL,
    DateCheckedIn date NOT NULL,
    Comment VARCHAR (255),
    PRIMARY KEY (RoomNo,CustomerID,CommentDate,DateCheckedIn), 
    FOREIGN KEY (DateCheckedIn,RoomNo,CustomerID) REFERENCES ROOMBOOKING(CheckInDate,RoomNo,CustomerID)
);
```

This is the error:

'Error Code: 1005. Can't create table 'new_schema.CUSTOMERFEEDBACK' (errno: 150)'

Comment: for the customer feedback table i only need 1 primary key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to rearrange your references

From this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (DateCheckedIn,RoomNo,CustomerID) REFERENCES ROOMBOOKING(CheckInDate,RoomNo,CustomerID)
```

To this:

```
FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID,DateCheckedIn,RoomNo) REFERENCES ROOMBOOKING(CustomerID,CheckInDate,RoomNo)
```

Since that is how you set your primary keys in ROOMBOOKING

Comment: OH MY GOD! IT WORKS! I didnt know the arrangements matter, thanks